# Find records in a table based on condition using SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I have a table student_course as below:-

```
student course
 1        a
 2        a
 1        b
 4        a
 5        d
 2        d
 5        a
```

i need to find all the rows where course=a and course not in b. result should be:-

```
student course
 2        a
 4        a
 5        a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM student_course
WHERE course = 'a' AND student NOT IN 
(
 SELECT student FROM student_course a
 WHERE course = 'b' 
)
```

Comment: This would return all rows that have 'a', because it's not 'b', and that's true for all a-rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
select student
from student_course 
group by student
having sum(case when course = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when course = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM student_course T1
LEFT JOIN student_course T2 ON T1.student = T2.student AND T2.course = 'B'
WHERE T1.course = 'A' AND T2.student IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from student_course
where course = 'a' and student not in (select student from student_course where course = 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM student_course
WHERE course = 'a'
AND student NOT IN (SELECT student
                    FROM student_course
                    WHERE course = 'b');
```

Comment: FYI `Not In` will fail when `subquery` returns a `NULL` value

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT ca.Student, ca.Course 
FROM student_course ca 
WHERE ca.course = 'a' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM student_course cb 
                    WHERE ca.Student = cb.Student AND cb.course = 'b' )
```